# How to list all elements from a column in a TextBox from SharePoint?

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, collections, splistitem

I wrote this code and it gives me only the last element of the column in a list. How can I get all elements in the `TextBox`?

```
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(myquery);

foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    if (item["Title"] != null)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = (string)item["Title"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the text within the text box at each iteration, so you only see the last value... Try this:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " " + (string)item["Title"];
```

Comment: Just figured to ask why you would do this? if you are trying to add a text box for each item, this solution will not work...

Comment: Hi onzur, thank you. it works. I want to add items of a sharepoint-list in a dropdownlist.

Comment: Sounds good, but I'm not sure is the best way... You can try the following:

Check this out: [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/demo-populate-a-drop-down-list-box-from-a-sharepoint-list-HA010254912.aspx)

Comment: thx. for the link. it was helpful. I wanted to mark your answer as good, but don't know it how it works

Comment: I made it with the DropDownList. It is easier to get the elements of a sharepointlist in a dropdownlist than in a textbox. :)              thx for the link. it was helpful. I wanted to mark your answer as good, but don't know it how it works

Comment: It's fine... I'm glad it worked. [I think you have to click on the check next to the answer...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)